# How to make a reference to the Variable in java and not to the Type of it

Tags: java, var

I have a specific question, so I start with an example:

I have some values of type String saved in variables as follows:

```
String one = "someValue";
String two = "anotherValue";
String three = "the last one";
```

and so on. This is of course a simple example, in the fact it will be  methods that returns String Type and I save it in Variables to use further in code;

I also have a List of Strings that contains some namespaces, that should be a name of xml-elements:

```
List<String> namespaces = new ArrayList<Sting>(Arrays.asList("example:org:one", "example:org:two", "example:org:three"); //and so on
```

It will be seems as

```
<example:org:one></example:org:one><example:org:two></example:org:two><example:org:three></example:org:three>
```

in xml - document. But of course they also have some values, which are saved in String Variables ('one', 'two', 'three' respect.) and I would like to make a reference on it in Java code, but explicitly, not implicitly. Say, use as value 'one' -> but not a String 'one', but a Variable, which name is ONE. GOT THE IDEA?:

```
for(String s : namespaces) {
    String[] arrayOfNamespaces = s.split(":");
    int lengthOfArrayOfNamespaces = arrayOfNamespaces.length;
    xmlBuilder.with(s, arrayOfNamespaces[lengthOfArrayOfNamespaces - 1]);   
    }
```

Is it possible? Is there something in java, that make a reference to a variable with the particular name in code: I believe it would be as something like Casting to VAR or as Annotation (maybe somebody had made something like this) :

```
...
xmlBuilder.with(s, @Var arrayOfNamespaces[lengthOfArrayOfNamespaces - 1]);
```

Or Mapping is the only way to make it works?

Comment: You can't implicitly create a reference to a reference, You can pass an reference to an object which contains a reference. I am not clear on what you expect `@Var` to do.

Comment: Why not just keep the mapping of elements and traverse the document if you want to get the reference.

Comment: You can use [Javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/) or [ASM](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http://asm.ow2.org/&ei=3TMOUs6oNMGCrgfWqoDIBQ&usg=AFQjCNEv2IRP-KCv_PInxMBDtMibNLnWlw&bvm=bv.50768961,d.bmk) ([Example)](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial2.html#add). But I would use a Map.

Comment: @user - yes, it seems to be right decision to use bytecode level for my question, but If it is the only way, I'd rather use mapping =)

Comment: @RomanC - I work with legacy code and sometimes there is no any proper implementation or the logic of code has to be changed, and in order to not write the code over again, I believe, that it is some sort of quick solution of my problem (as I supposed with annotations, for instance). I'm looking forward new solutions though!